# Android :: Background Thread across the Application

Tags: android

I want to detect the audio headphone to play the audio file. but I need to detect that earphone is connected or not every time in each tab like album, artist, playlist, etc. I  when I am trying to do it. I am creating separate asynctask to detect the device in each tab. its working fine. but if I am giving more stress to the application like changing over the tabs fastly. My App's GUI i getting freezed. i think its beacuse of running more thread or thread pool got dumpped.

So I have an other idea that only one background thread will run to check the device connectivity and functions. we need to share the status to everywhere in the app. But I have no idea to how to implement it.

Any Idea or sample codes on this?

Check [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646113/android-ui-changes-from-shared-background-thread) Also.

Answer (score 0):

To detect the headset plug is easy job same as usb detect one you need to  register a receiver with **action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG" />** and receiver would be active

public class PhoneUsbReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(
            "android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED")){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Usb-connected..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        Log.i("Arpit", "USB connected..");
    }
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(
            "android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED")) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "USB dis-connected..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        Log.i("Arpit", "USB dis-connected..");
    }

    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(
            "android.intent.action.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG")) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "HEADSET_PLUG-connected..",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("Arpit", "HEADSET_PLUG-connected..");
    }

    if (intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "HEADSET_PLUG-connected..",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("Arpit", "HEADSET_PLUG-connected..");
    } else if (intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "HEADSET_PLUG-dis-connected..",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("Arpit", "HEADSET_PLUG-dis-connected..");
    }

}
```

}

Now Declare the Receiver in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneUsbReceiver" >

            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

To share data between tabs, you could create a HeadphoneHelper class and kep the current status in a static field.

e.g.:

```
public class HeadphoneHelper {
    private static Boolean connected;

    public static Boolean isConnected() {
        return connected;
    }

    public static Boolean setConnected(Boolean isNowConnected) {
        connected = isNowConnected;
    }


}
```

And then using it in your tabs:

```
Boolean headphoneConnected = HeadphoneHelper.isConnected();
```